# Why was cakePHP designed to use Inheritance over Composition even though it's mostly considered a bad design?

Tags: oop, cakephp, design-patterns, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP Applications being made in our company tends to become unmaintainable as it becomes more complex. I figured that one specific reason is inheritance which makes the functions in child classes depends a lot on it's parent classes and vice-versa (implementing template method pattern). Why is CakePHP designed this way and not friendly in using Dependency Injection, Strategies, or Factory patterns?

Comment: Can you elaborate with a specific example of composition over inheritance?

Comment: Examples or it didn't happen. I've worked on huge applications made with CakePHP and we never ran into an issue. This sounds more like bad application architecture. Nothing prevents you from creating a service / domain model layer. If you think you must put everything into the table objects, well, it's your fault. :) And this is a common mistake I've seen. I've started to work on https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-service-layer to give people a direction and I don't think a DI container is missing.

Comment: @burzum it's good to know that your group or company never ran into an issue. That's a very rare thing since every developers and companies I know experienced some issues during development. You must be part of a really good company with true development experts.

Comment: I never said we haven't had any problems, we just never had any architectural problems related or caused by the framework. I've worked for cakedc.com and now I lead the development in another company. I recommend you to read my answer, especially the last paragraph and act accordingly. You basically blame the tool without providing context and examples. Until you do that I'm very sure your company is doing something wrong and not the tool.

Comment: @burzum Dude did you even read my question? Which part is related to architectural problems? I actually read your statement "We never ran into an issue" is pretty synonymous to "We haven't had any problems".. The idea of stackoverflow is to help and not to be right or not to boast yourself or your position or your achievements cause those are not part of my question. I need people to answer well, if you can't, it's better to ignore my question.

Comment: I've been hearing news that StackOverflow became so TOXIC nowadays, this is one of the reasons why I asked this question this way,. They said people here focus more on RULES on questioning rather than trying to HELP, and I see that is TRUE... The thing is if you don't understand the question, like you still need examples to do so, don't bother to answer. But if you can't really understand the question w/o example and you genuinely wants to help; then ask for examples respectfully so aspiring programmers won't bother to visit this site to ask for help... Until then, I won't recommend this site.

Comment: Did YOU even read my answer? Especially the last paragraph? Your "question" is blaming the framework without showing *any* code nor giving *any* proof of what *exactly* is wrong with the framework. So I think it's your code.

Since you're not very polite nor showing any will to provide context and examples of your problem I've decided to downvote and to close vote your question because it is simply, due to the lack of any further information, to broad to be answered. You *won't* receive more help on this because you fail to provide the information I've asked now multiple times for.

Answer (score 3):

There is not such a bad design as you claim in the framework. Sure, there are probably things that could be done better but I would like to see a more substantial critic including solid arguments and examples. I assume you're not using the framework as it was intended.

Let me quote the first paragraph from [this page](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/03/11/domain-driven-design-and-mvc-architectures/).

> According to Eric Evans, Domain-driven design (DDD) is not a technology or a methodology. It’s a different way of thinking about how to organize your applications and structure your code. This way of thinking complements very well the popular MVC architecture. The domain model provides a structural view of the system. Most of the time, applications don’t change, what changes is the domain. **MVC, however, doesn’t really tell you how your model should be structured. That’s why some frameworks don’t force you to use a specific model structure, instead, they let your model evolve as your knowledge and expertise grows.**

You're not showing code (for a reason?) so I *guess* your problem comes from stuffing everything into the table objects in `src/Model/Table/` or doing something similar.

But you're totally free to create a folder structure like

- /src/Service
- /src/Model/Domain

and then simply instantiate services as you need them in your controller actions. A service could be for example `\App\Service\User\Registration` and using objects from `App\Model\Domain\User`.

I agree that the framework in fact doesn't provide any recommendation or template structure for how this could look like. For exactly this topic [there is a discussion going on here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11260). Because of a lack of such a structure [I've started working on a plugin that provides this](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-service-layer). The plugin doesn't require but suggest the usage of DI containers for the people who want them.

Given the whole fancy topic around DI and DDD so far I would say there is not the one way to get things right but different paths as long as the code is easy to maintain. And honestly, as long as this goal is archived I really don't care about how you call it. :) I think many people tend do make this topic to academic instead of simply trying to be practical.

Not everybody is even needing that structure. It depends on if you're building a RAD CRUD application or a more complex app. Not every application needs a DDD approach. There are so many shades of gray when it comes to design the business layer, no matter how the framework would do it, somebody would always complain about it.

I *personally* almost never missed a DI container in CakePHP, not even in the biggest project having more than ~560 database tables which was a hospital management solution and it just worked well.

I would suggest you to ask a more specific question about your approach how you structured your code and showing your structure and code and then asking for advice on how to improve it instead of blaming the tool you're using in the first place without providing context.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CakePHP v3 can not compare to the Zend3/Laminas, Symfony or Laravel.It is 7-8 years behind the other frameworks.If you are using cake for years or it is your 1st and last framework it is normal to not realise that.But if you have to use it after Zend 3... cake seems like really bad ecosystem.

1. Bad documentation
2. Bad ORM
3. Poor Routing system
4. Bad Templating engine
5. Bad idea to mix Data Mapper and Active Record
6. DIC is totally missing
7. Components - not good but not terrible
   ...
8. And many more thinks that should not be underestimated like - lack of **GOOD** tutorials, pluigns/addons/packages

The above thinks make developers to follow bad practices that adds a lot of technical depth.
If you care just for - **it works!** But not how it works and why it is bad, cake will fit ok for you.

Cake can not scale as good as Symfony/Laminas if you are doing big project.(yea AWS/GC can help for scaling a lot of thinks but not for scaling source code)
Cake doesn't allow you rapid development like Laravel/Symfony for decent project.

I'm wondering who and **WHY** would start a new project today using Cake as it has **zero** benefits over the other frameworks.
Probably only devs who used only Cake for last decade and do not want to start learning new technologies or devs that thinks **SOLID** is just a fancy hype with zero benefits like **design patterns**, **DRY** and **KISS**

Answer (score -2):

CakePHP framework supplies user interaction with databases using **Active record**, it means that exist a high coupling between business layer and database layer which has negative effects in unit testing and because of that the framework is not friendly with Dependency Injection. The same issue happens with Factory pattern, high coupling mentioned before makes more difficult use simulated objects in unit testing.

Hope it helps!

Alberto

Comment: Please show an example of the coupling you're talking about. I've *never* missed a DIC in CakePHP. Examples please were you think it is mandatory? Actually I think most people simply use a DIC like a super global, like a bucket for everything.

Comment: CakePHP uses DataMapper pattern that described well in Martin Fowler books.